# jQuery Selectbox Append Options OnChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I'm working with jQuery and a plugin called jQuery.SelectBox

I have 3 selectboxes, selecting an option in the first selectbox will change the options in the second one.

My problem comes when I try to insert values in the second selectbox via append function in jQuery. Everything works fine but the new options are not clickable.

You can see the problem right here: http://incubadora.gelattina.com/impac/galeria.html (scroll down and to the right), there are the three selectboxes.

Comment: Can you please ad a link to the plugin you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you put in a normal select, and this does a dynamic creation of a stylized 'select box' via jQuery.

The problem, I would guess, is that, since you're adding items after the select box's initialization, the new items don't have any sort of action listeners on them.

I can't seem to find any documentation on this SelectBox plugin, but you need to find a way to Bind the click and hover actions provided by SelectBox onto you're newly added items.

You can try calling the `.selectbox();` function on the select elements after you've added the new options to see if that works.

Comment: Hi. This is the plugin: http://info.wsisiz.edu.pl/~suszynsk/jQuery/demos/jquery-selectbox/ couldn't posted before because of the 'new user' rule.

Indeed, that's the problem. I tried applying the selectbox effect to the first selectbox and then, when an option is selected, apply to the second one, and worked fine!!!

But I can't still make it work the way I want.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I wrote a select box plugin called [Selectzor](http://jeremy.infinicastonline.com/2010/01/selectzor/), just for this reason.

It should accomplish everything you need.